# T-SNE good clustering but SVM classification poor

Tags: scikit-learn, clustering, svm, word2vec, doc2vec

I am trying to classify in 4 different classes, paragraph embedding vector computed with doc2vec using an non-linear svm over them.
When I visualize the embeddings using tensorboard t-sne I can see that they are clustered quite well as in the image.
[image: Embedding visualization for t-sne]
However, when I train the svm (with rbf kernel and grid search) I obtain an f1-score of 60% that given the figure seems quite low.
Is it common to obtain good cluster with t-sne and bad results with svm?